# Gurobi Python - RHS "changes" when I move code to a server

Tags: python, gurobi

I wrote a transportation linear program on my personal computer in python/gurobi.  A typical constraint for demand node `j` might look like this:

```
m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i1, j1] for (i1, j1) in arcs.select('*', j)) == demand[j])
```

where

`x[i, j]` is a decision variable for flow on edge (i,j)

`arcs` is the set of all edges between supply and demand nodes

`demand[j]` is a known fractional constant of demand required at j

When I test this code out on my personal computer, it works fine.  However, when I move it to my organization's computing cluster and try to run it, the right hand side (`demand[j]`) is not the same and I get incorrect values for `x[i,j]'s`.

Answer (score 0):

When I add `float` around the right hand side, it works again.

```
m.addConstr(quicksum(x[i1, j1] for (i1, j1) in arcs.select('*', j)) == float(demand[j]))
```

(I don't know why this problem exists or if it's only on Python)